# Maximum likelihood of Compound Poisson Distributions

Tags: r

I'm trying to compute a maximum likelihood of the compound Poisson-Gamma distribution in R. The distribution  is defined by $ \sum_{j=1}^{N} Y_j $ where $Y_n$ is i.i.d sequence independent $gamma(k,\theta)$ values and $N$ is a Poisson distribution with parameter $\beta$. I'm trying to estimate the parameters $\theta$ and $\beta$ without luck.

Comment: This will probably get more useful results on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com); I'm voting to migrate it there. If I needed to do this, I would do it by brute force/approximation.  We know that the distribution of the sum of j Gamma deviates with parameters (shape=k, scale=theta) is Gamma(j * k, theta), so we can define the distribution as a mixture of Gammas: Prob(x|\beta,k,\theta) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty dPois(j|\beta)*Gamma(j * k,\theta).  The problem is that it's an infinite sum - unless there's a closed-form solution you might have to truncate the summation

Comment: I would probably look in Bailey's stochastic processes book or Pielou's statistical ecology book (or Johnson/Kotz) for more information about the distribution/what's known about the probability distribution

Comment: Wikipedia suggests that this distribution is equivalent to a Tweedie distribution, for which there are resources available in R (`library("sos"); findFn("tweedie")` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution#Compound_Poisson_Gamma_distribution

Comment: unfortunately this package does not contain a function to estimate this parameters .

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do something similar, but for a negative binomial distribution, then you can use the the function **negbin.mle** from the package **Rfast**

```
y <- rpois(100, 2)

Rfast::negbin.mle(y)
```

Output

```
$iters
[1] 5

$loglik
[1] -162.855

$param
success probability  number of failures                mean 
          0.9963271         480.1317031           1.7700000
```

Also if you run the command:

```
Rfast::negbin.mle
```

You can see what the function is computing.

You can also check the functions manual with:

```
?Rfast::negbin.mle
```

**Edit:**

Unfortunately I haven't found something that perfectly fits your answer.
As Ben states, this answer is for a Poisson with Gamma-distributed mean.

Comment: I don't think this works.  NB is a Poisson with Gamma-distributed mean; OP wants a sum of Gammas

Comment: @BenBolker You are right, I had misunderstood the question

Comment: @linabina It is working, I just tested it. The problem is that as it appears it doesn't perfectly fit your question. So I will edit my answer.